# On create a career solutions I get value 0 in database laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to add some extra fields on my form.I ve already done, I have the first field called `Format`:

```
    <span class="input-group-addon col col-3" ><i  class="icon-tag"></i></span>
    <div class="col col-3" id="format">
                                            <label class="label" >Format</label>
<label class="select">
    <!--    {!! Form::select('event_format_id',$formatList,null,['required']) !!} -->
    <select name="topic_format_id" class="event_format" required onchange="yesnoCheck2(this);">
    <option value="0" category_url="select">Select</option>
    <option value="1" category_url="e-learning">E-learning</option>
    <option value="2" category_url="classroom">Classroom</option>
    <option value="3" category_url="on-site">On-site</option>
    <option value="4" category_url="live-web">Live web</option>
    <option value="5" category_url="mentoring">Mentoring</option>
    <option value="6" category_url="blended">Blended (Classroom + Online)</option>
    <option value="7" category_url="practice-based">Practice based</option>
    <option value="8" category_url="home-schooling">Home schooling</option>
    <option value="9" category_url="other">Other</option>
    </select>
        </label>
            </div>
```

What I did before:

*This from my query*

```
career_solutions_format.category as event_format

INNER JOIN career_solutions_format
ON career_solutions_format.id = career_solutions.topic_format_id
```

or this

```
$temp_soluation['event_format'] = $career_solution->event_format;

// return $request['category_id'];
       $career_solution = \App\CareerSolution::create([
       'subject' => $extract->title,
       'topic_category_id' => $category_id[0],
       'topic_subcategory_id' => $request['topic_subcategory_id'],
       'topic_format_id' => $request['topic_format_id'],
```

*Here is my code - view part*

```
<div class="career_solution_field" style="display:none">
                                    <div class="row ">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon col col-3" style="top: 32px;position: relative;height: 33px;width: 6% !important;left: 17px;border: 1px solid #bbb;"><i style="left: -6px;position: relative;top: 2px;font-size: 12px" class="icon-tag"></i></span>

    <div class="col col-3" style="width: 30% !important;position: relative;right: 10px;">
        <label class="label" style="right: 35px;position: relative">Sub Topic</label>
        <label class="select">
            <select name="topic_subcategory_id" class="sub_category js-example-basic-single" required>
                </select>
                </label>
                    </div>
                <span class="input-group-addon col col-3" style="top: 32px;position: relative;height: 33px;width: 6% !important;left: 7px;border: 1px solid #bbb;"><i style="left: -6px;position: relative;top: 2px;font-size: 12px" class="icon-tag"></i></span>
                <div class="col col-3" style="width: 30% !important;position: relative;right: 19px;display: none" id="format">
            <label class="label" style="right: 35px;position: relative">Format</label>
                <label class="select">
            <!--    {!! Form::select('event_format_id',$formatList,null,['required']) !!} -->
            <select name="topic_format_id" class="event_format" required onchange="yesnoCheck2(this);">
            <option  value="0" category_url="select">Select</option>
            <option value="1" category_url="e-learning">E-learning</option>
            <option value="2" category_url="classroom">Classroom</option>
            <option value="3" category_url="on-site">On-site</option>
            <option value="4" category_url="live-web">Live web</option>
            <option value="5" category_url="mentoring">Mentoring</option>
            <option value="6" category_url="blended">Blended (Classroom + Online)</option>
            <option value="7" category_url="practice-based">Practice based</option>
            <option value="8" category_url="home-schooling">Home schooling</option>
            <option value="9" category_url="other">Other</option>
            </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

*Here is my code - controller part*

```
$career_solutions_data = DB::select(" 
SELECT 
career_solutions.id,
career_solutions.user_id,  
career_solutions.subject, 
career_solutions.date, 
career_solutions.public, 
career_solutions.views, 
career_solutions.optional, 
career_solutions.on_offer, 
users.username, 
users.profile_picture, 
categories.category, 
categories.category_url, 
categories.color, 
career_solutions_categories.category as sub_category,
career_solutions_format.category as event_format

FROM career_solutions 

INNER JOIN categories 
ON categories.id = career_solutions.topic_category_id 

INNER JOIN career_solutions_format
ON career_solutions_format.id = career_solutions.topic_format_id

INNER JOIN career_solutions_categories 
ON career_solutions_categories.id = career_solutions.topic_subcategory_id 

INNER JOIN users 
ON users.id = career_solutions.user_id 


INNER JOIN privacy_settings 
ON privacy_settings.user_id = users.id 

WHERE users.deleted_at IS NULL 
AND ( 
(privacy_settings.career_solutions = 0 AND public = 1 ) 
OR (users.id IN ( 

SELECT contacts.contact_id 
FROM contacts 
WHERE contacts.user_id = $id 
) 
) 
) 

OR users.id = $id 

ORDER BY date desc limit 5000 
"); 


                // $career_solutions_data;

                foreach ($career_solutions_data as $career_solution) 
                {

                    preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $career_solution->optional, $image);
                    if(isset($image['src']))
                    {
                        $type_picture = $image['src'];
                    }
                    else{
                        $type_picture = "";
                    }

                    $temp_soluation = array();
                    $temp_soluation['type'] = 'Career Solution';
                    $temp_soluation['typee'] = 'briefcase';
                    $temp_soluation['subject'] = $career_solution->subject;

                    $temp_soluation['information'] = $career_solution->optional;
                    $temp_soluation['category'] = $career_solution->category;
                    $temp_soluation['category_url'] = $career_solution->category_url;
                    $temp_soluation['color'] = $career_solution->color;
                    $temp_soluation['all_url'] = 'search-career-solutions';
                    $temp_soluation['type_url'] = 'view-career-solutions';
                    $temp_soluation['id'] = $career_solution->id;
                    $temp_soluation['date'] = $career_solution->date;
                    $temp_soluation['public'] = $career_solution->public;
                    $temp_soluation['sub_category'] = $career_solution->sub_category;
                    $temp_soluation['event_format'] = $career_solution->event_format;
                    $temp_soluation['on_offer'] = $career_solution->on_offer;
                    $temp_soluation['username'] = $career_solution->username;
                    $temp_soluation['roleMe'] = $career_solution->optional;
                    $temp_soluation['role'] = \App\User::select('id')->where('id', '=', $career_solution->user_id)->first()->role;
                    $temp_soluation['profile_picture'] = $career_solution->profile_picture;
                    $temp_soluation['type_picture'] = $type_picture;
                    // $news_events_opinions[] = $temp_soluation;
                    $my_career_solution[] = $temp_soluation;
                }
            }


            $news_events_opinions;
            if(count($news_events_opinions) > 0)
            {
                foreach ($news_events_opinions as $key => $row) {
                    $date[$key] = $row['date'];
                }

                array_multisort($date, SORT_DESC, $news_events_opinions);
            }


            $data['news_events_opinions'] = $news_events_opinions;
            $data['career_solutions'] = $my_career_solution;
            $data['filter'] = $filter;

            $cone = array_merge($news_events_opinions,$my_career_solution);


            $data['page'] = Input::get('page');
            // return $data['page'];
            if(empty($data['page']))
            {
                $data['page'] = 1;
            }
            $perPage = 12;
            // $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;


            $data['paginator'] = new Paginator($cone,count($cone), $perPage, $data['page'],['path' => Request::url()]);

              if(\Session::get('extract') != "")
              {
                  $data['extract'] = \Session::get('extract');
              }else{
                  $data['extract'] = "";
              }


            // $user = \App\User::with('event','news','opinion','career_solution','invitation')->findOrfail($id);




 return view('noticeboard.noticeboard',$data);


        }
        else{
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }




    public function create(requ $request)
    {

        if ($user = Sentinel::check())
        {
            $extract = Embedly::extract($request['extract'], [
                                'maxwidth' => '500'
                               ]);


            if(isset($extract->error_code) && $extract->error_code == '400'){
                $extract->url = "Invaild URL";    
                $extract->title = $request['extract'];    
                $extract->description = $request['extract']." Invaild URL";    
                $extract->provider_url = "Invaild URL";    
            }
            if(isset($extract->error_code) && $extract->error_code == '404'){
                flash('Url is not available.', 'warning');
                return redirect('noticeboard');
            }
            $category_id = \App\Category::where('category_url', '=' ,$request['category_url'])->pluck('id');
            // return $category_id[0];
            if(isset($extract->media) && isset($extract->media->type) && $extract->media->type == 'video'){
                 $emmbed_script = $extract->media->html;
                 $url = $this->convert_text($emmbed_script);
                 $a = explode('?', $url);
                 $b = str_replace('src=', '', $a[1]);
                 $information = "<div id='career-notice'>
                                    <div id='link-info' class='group'>
                                        <a>
                                            <iframe src='".$b."' width='100%' height='281'></iframe>
                                        </a>
                                        <br><br>
                                        <div class='info'>Article first seen on:<br>
                                            <div class='title' style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>
                                                <a href='".$extract->url."'>".$extract->title."
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <p>".$extract->description."</p>
                                            <div class='href'>
                                                <a href='".$extract->provider_url."'>Htmlstream</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>";
            }
            else if(!empty($extract->images))
            {
                $information = "<div id='career-notice'>
                                    <div id='link-info' class='group'>
                                        <a>
                                            <img src='".$extract->images[0]->url."' style='width:100%' title='".$extract->title."' />
                                        </a>
                                        <br><br>
                                        <div class='info'>Article first seen on:<br>
                                            <div class='title' style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>
                                                <a href='".$extract->url."'>".$extract->title."
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <p>".$extract->description."</p>
                                            <div class='href'>
                                                <a href='".$extract->provider_url."'>Htmlstream</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>";
                            // die;
            }
            else{

                $information = "<div id='career-notice'>
                                <div id='link-info' class='group'>
                                    <div class='info'>Article first seen on:
                                        <div class='title' style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>
                                            <a href='".$extract->url."'>".$extract->title."
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>".$extract->description."</p>
                                        <div class='href'>
                                            <a href='".$extract->provider_url."'>Htmlstream</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>";
            }
            // return $request->all();
            if($request['type'] == "")
            {
                flash('please Choose Setting', 'warning');
                return redirect('noticeboard');
            }


            if($request['type'] == "my-career-soluation")
            {
                if($request['category_url'] == "" )
                {
                    flash('please Choose Category', 'warning');
                    return redirect('noticeboard');
                }
                if($request['topic_subcategory_id'] == "" )
                {
                    flash('please Choose Sub category', 'warning');
                    return redirect('noticeboard');
                }
                if($request['topic_format_id'] == "" )
                {
                    flash('please Choose Format', 'warning');
                    return redirect('noticeboard');
                }


                if($request['location'] == "" )
                {
                    flash('please Choose Location', 'warning');
                    return redirect('noticeboard');
                }
               if($request['on_offer'] == "" )
                {
                    $request['on_offer'] = 0;
                }

                // return $request['category_id'];
                $career_solution = \App\CareerSolution::create([
                        'subject' => $extract->title,
                        'topic_category_id' => $category_id[0],
                        'topic_subcategory_id' => $request['topic_subcategory_id'],
                        'topic_format_id' => $request['topic_format_id'],
                        'quantity' => 1,
                        'expires_at' => '0000-00-00',
                        'location' => $request['location'],
                        'on_offer' => $request['on_offer'],
                        'optional' => $information,
                        'user_id' => $user->id,
                        'public' => $request['public'],
                        'url' => $extract->url,
                        'date' => time(),
                        'added' => time(),
                        // 'city' => $request['city'],
                        // 'employment_type' => $request['employment_type'],
                        // 'estimated_salary' => $request['estimated_salary'],
                    ]);



                if($career_solution != "")
                {
                    flash('Career Solution has been Created Successfully', 'success');
                }else{
                    flash('Career Solution has not Created Successfully', 'warning');
                }

                $previousUrl = URL::previous();

                return redirect($previousUrl);

              // return redirect('my-career-solution');
            // return \Redirect::route('editprofile')
            //             ->with( 'tabname','careerpath' );

                // return "news";
            }
            return redirect('noticeboard');
        }
        else{
            return redirect('login');
        }

    }






    public function store(requ $request)
    {

        // return $request['category_url'];
        if ($user = Sentinel::check())
        {
            $category_id = \App\Category::where('category_url', '=' ,$request['category_url'])->pluck('id');
            // return $request->all();
            if($request['type'] == "" )
            {
                flash('please Choose Type', 'warning');
                return redirect('noticeboard');
            }
            if($request['type'] == "news")
            {
                if($request['category_url'] == "" )
                {
                    // flash()->overlay('Modal Message', 'Modal Title');
                    flash('please Choose Category', 'warning');
                    return redirect('noticeboard');
                }

                $news = \App\News::create([
                        'user_id' => $user->id,
                        'subject' => $request['subject'],
                        'information' => $request['information'],
                        'public' => $request['public'],
                        'category_id' => $category_id[0],
                        'image_path' => 'assets/img/no-profile-photo.jpg',
                        'date' => time(),
                        'added' => time(),
                    ]);

                if($news != "")
                {
                    flash('News has been Created Successfully', 'success');
                }else{
                    flash('News has not Created Successfully', 'warning');
                }

                $previousUrl = URL::previous();

                return redirect($previousUrl);
              // return redirect('news');
            // return \Redirect::route('editprofile')
            //             ->with( 'tabname','careerpath' );

                // return "news";
            }





            if($request['type'] == "my-career-soluation")
            {
                if($request['category_url'] == "" )
                {
                    flash('please Choose Category', 'warning');
                    return redirect('noticeboard');
                }
                if($request['topic_subcategory_id'] == "" )
                {
                    flash('please Choose Sub Category', 'warning');
                    return redirect('noticeboard');
                }
                 if($request['topic_format_id'] == "" )
                {
                    flash('please Choose Format', 'warning');
                    return redirect('noticeboard');
                }
                if($request['location'] == "" )
                {
                    flash('please Choose Location', 'warning');
                    return redirect('noticeboard');
                }
                if($request['on_offer'] == "" )
                {
                    flash('please Choose Offer', 'warning');
                    return redirect('noticeboard');
                }

                // return $request['career_city'];
                $career_solution = \App\CareerSolution::create([
                        'subject' => $request['subject'],
                        'topic_category_id' => $category_id[0],
                        'topic_subcategory_id' => $request['topic_subcategory_id'],
                        'topic_format_id' => $request['topic_format_id'],
                        'quantity' => $request['quantity'],
                        'expires_at' => $request['expires_at'],
                        'location' => $request['location'],
                        'on_offer' => $request['on_offer'],
                        'optional' => $request['information'],
                        'user_id' => $user->id,
                        'public' => $request['public'],
                        'date' => time(),
                        'added' => time(),
                        'city' => $request['career_city'],
                        'employment_type' => $request['employment_type'],
                        'estimated_salary' => $request['estimated_salary'],
                    ]);



                if($career_solution != "")
                {
                    flash('Career Solution has been Created Successfully', 'success');
                }else{
                    flash('Career Solution has not Created Successfully', 'warning');
                }

                $previousUrl = URL::previous();

                return redirect($previousUrl);
              // return redirect('my-career-solution');

            }



            return $request->all();
        }
        else{
            return redirect('login');
        }

    }
```

In my controller I have some queries, but anything I did, every time is saved with value 0 in database, instead of 1-9 like in my list.I already have `topic_subcategory_id` which is saving in db ( db : `career_solutions_categories`.I need to save it in database(`table career_solutions`, column `topic_format_id`). Can you help me please?What I did wrong in my code?

At `dd($request['topic_format_id']);` = "4" or "1" which is the correct value from list, but it doesn't saving in database.

This is a link with my table : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDNoz.jpg

Comment: which column saving with value 0? topic_format_id ? 

try dd($request['topic_format_id']); and update the question with result

Comment: Thank you for the answer! dd($request['topic_format_id']);  is "4"  or "1". So, this returns me the correct value.But in db I still have value 0.

Comment: Does it work if you manually set the value `$career_solution->topic_format_id = $request['topic_format_id'];$career_solution->save();` instead of passing it to `create`? If so you probably forgot to add the field to [the model's `fillable` property](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Comment: Thank you so much, now it's working! Please add an answer to pick yours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to set a model property using [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment) (e.g. the static `create` method) you need to make sure it's either included in the model's `$fillable` property or that the model has a `$guarded` property which doesn't include the property you want to set.